Overleaf table centering
I copied the code below from https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Tables.
The output shown on the website has this table centered on top of the caption.
However when I enter the same command in my overleaf document it has the table more to the right.
I have searched on stack overflow for an answer to this but they all discuss begin{center} and {centering} and \par of which I have tried but nothing works.
I would really appreciate it if someone could please help me with this.
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{||c c c c||} 
 \hline
 Col1 & Col2 & Col2 & Col3 \\ [0.5ex] 
 \hline\hline
 1 & 6 & 87837 & 787 \\ 
 2 & 7 & 78 & 5415 \\
 3 & 545 & 778 & 7507 \\
 4 & 545 & 18744 & 7560 \\
 5 & 88 & 788 & 6344 \\ [1ex] 
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{This is the caption for the first table.}
\label{table:1}
\end{table}

\end{document}


I tried the begin{center} end{center}, \centering and \par but nothing works.

Welcome to TSE. Please post a Minimal Working Example, instead of a code snippet.

I you insert your table in some article document. it is perfectly centered. From your code snipped is not possible to see, what is your problem. Extend it to complete small document, which reproduce your problem.

@Zarko Thank you for your reply. My document is very long so I am not sure what parts to include?

do not post your original document but post something  that shows the issue. Currently it is impossible to guess your problem, you have posted a fragment of code but we can not run it, and you have just said "nothing works" but you have not said what output you got or what error. Also try to give more reasonable tags, this is unrelated to overleaf (which is just where you are running tex) or latex3.

I made your fragment into a document and showed its output, which looks as expected, please edit to show the problem, or describe what output you expected.

Your table is perfectly (horizontally) centered within the text area, as is to be expected, but your text area is not centered on the paper. This comes because the left and right margin are not equal by default. You can check this by adding \usepackage{showframe} before the \begin{document}, and/or by adding \usepackage{layout} before \begin{document}, and \layout after.
